# Drawing list of pieces on the form

Tags: c#

First of all I'm new to the C# world.
I just started this year learning about C# with no programming background experience. 
I came here with a problem that I would like to get solved asap.
I managed to write a little code to create a list with Bitmaps including the draw positions.
What I'm trying to do is to draw every piece (picture of a dot) in the list on the form.
I've been working hours on this just trying to figure out how to get the list drawn on the form...
I placed comments behind the code to make it easier for the reader to understand whats it's for so it won't cause any brain damage or sweat to the reader. :p 
See below for my code:

**Form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private GridDrawing drawing;
    private Bitmap bmpPic;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bmpPic = new Bitmap("Dot.png"); // Picture(Dot 28*28 pixels)
        this.Paint += Form_Paint;

    }

    private void Form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        drawing = new GridDrawing(this, bmpPic, 6, 8); // Form, Bitmap, Rows, Columns
        foreach (var piece in drawing.Pieces)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmpPic, piece.Position);
        }
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

**GridDrawing.cs**

```
    public class GridDrawing
{
    private Bitmap bmpPic;
    private int columns;
    private int rows;
    private List<GridPiece> pieces;

    private Point position;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a grid with dots.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ctrl"></param>
    /// <param name="gridPic"></param>
    /// <param name="rows"></param>
    /// <param name="columns"></param>
    public GridDrawing(Control ctrl, Bitmap bmpPic, int rows, int columns)
    {
        this.bmpPic = bmpPic;                                         //The picture(Dot).
        this.rows = rows;                                             //The amount of rows in the matrix.
        this.columns = columns;                                       //The amount of columns in the matrix.

        this.pieces = new List<GridPiece>();                                            //Initializes the List GridPieces
        Point position = new Point(0, 0);                                               //Draw position of the picture(Dot)
        Size size = new Size(bmpPic.Width, bmpPic.Height);                              //Size of picture(Dot).

        for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++)             //A  with 6 rows
        {
            position.X = 0;                         //Puts the value X on 0 when it starts a new row.
            for (int j = 0; j <= columns; j++)      //A matrix with 8 columns
            {
                GridPiece s = new GridPiece(bmpPic, position);  // Creates a piece
                pieces.Add(s);                                  // Puts the piece that has to be drawn in the List<GridPiece>pieces
                position.X += size.Width;                       // Changes the width of the draw position
            }
            position.Y += size.Height;                          // Changes the height of the draw position
        }
    }

    public List<GridPiece> Pieces
    {
        get { return this.pieces; }
    }
}
```

**GridPiece.cs**

```
public class GridPiece
{
    private Bitmap bmpPic;
    private Point position;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor of GriedPiece
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bmpPic"></param>
    /// <param name="position"></param>
    public GridPiece(Bitmap bmpPic, Point position)
    {
        this.bmpPic = bmpPic;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public Point Position
    {
        get { return position; }
    }
}
```

Could anyone pretty please help me solve my issue?
I updates the code several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the form's `Paint` event, and use the methods in `e.Graphics` to draw your pieces in a loop.

(Probably `e.Graphics.DrawImage`, or perhaps `FillCircle`)

It would look something like

```
void Form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) { 
    foreach(var piece in drawing.Pieces) {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmpPic, piece.Position);
    }
}
```

The paint event is raised every time the forms needs to be drawn.

When the pieces move, you need to manually force the form to repaint by calling `Invalidate()`.

Comment: Could you please give me an example code so its easier for me to understand? :)

Comment: Where are my manner, first of all I want to thank you for your time.
I tried your example and Ill edit the original post so you can see what I did.
The piece.position states that its inaccessible duo to its protection level. I already tried making it public (temporary just to test). Any tips to fix this?

Comment: You need to make them public.  You should make public readonly properties that expose them

Comment: Awesome! Thought so. Thats probably why you used a capital for piece.Position <---

Comment: Yes.  You should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.

Comment: Calling the Form_Paint method with an PaintEventhandler didnt seem the work for me...
btnStart.Click += new PaintEventHandler(this.Form_Paint);
Any tips for calling Form_Paint ?

Comment: You need to add the handler to the form's `Paint` event. (`Form.Paint += Form_Paint;`)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by that. Could you please explain it with an example? My knowledge about eventhandlers is very poor >_<

Comment: You need to write `this.Paint += Form_Paint` to add the handler to the `Paint` event.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx

Comment: Note that you may want to draw them in a `Panel` instead of the form itself.  If so, handle the `Panel`'s `Paint` event.

Comment: I'm kinda feel stupid at the moment...
I put this.Paint += Form_Paint; in constructor Form1 I have absolutely no clue where else to put it.
 Next I tried to call the PaintEventHandler by doing this:  

btnStart.Click += new PaintEventHandler(this.Form_Paint);   

It keeps telling me "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler'"

Comment: You can't add a Paint handler to the Click event, and there is no reason to either.

Comment: Pretty clear to me!
Anyway I updated the code. Having one problem tho with GridDrawing.cs
Keeps telling me "Inconsistend accessibility: property type 'List<GridPiece>' is less accessible than property 'GridDrawing.Pieces'. I tried googling for a solution but I couldn't find any solution to this. You have any idea how to fix this? I'm really sorry for being a persistent bugger.

Comment: You need to make the `GridPiece` class `public`.

Comment: Youre awesome dude! That fixed the problem.
It draws the dots like it should.
Any clue why the dots (pictures) are larger then the original .png file?